# Genuinely stumped. I can't divide using a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I loaded some state by state covid data from: https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/pressroom/sosmap/covid19_mortality_final/COVID19.htm

Then I loaded it into a data frame and try to do some basic analysis. But I immediately got an annoying NaN that I can't seem to make go away.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

covid_mortality_data_filename = '../data/covid-mortality.csv'
covid_df = pd.read_csv(covid_mortality_data_filename)
intermediate_df = covid_df.groupby("STATE").sum()
intermediate_df['DEATHS'] = intermediate_df['DEATHS'].astype(float) # desperate move
covid_df["Deaths pct"] = intermediate_df["DEATHS"] / intermediate_df["DEATHS"].sum().astype(float)
```

Yet I get all NaNs in the "Deaths pct" column. This just feels like a broken API. I've tried several things. Idk what to do.

EDIT: Thank you everyone for the responses! I get it now. The two frames don't have the same index. The below fixes my problem and gives me the data I want:

```
intermediate_df["Deaths pct"] = intermediate_df["DEATHS"] / float(intermediate_df["DEATHS"].sum().astype(float))
```

I.e. I don't actually need `covid_df` after doing the `groupby()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain NaN values because your dataframe `covid_df` and your series `intermediate_df` do not have the same indexing.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
covid_mortality_data_filename = '../data/covid-mortality.csv'
covid_df = pd.read_csv(covid_mortality_data_filename) # Indexed by integer index
intermediate_df = covid_df.groupby("STATE").sum() # Indexed by STATE
```

To solve your issue, you must merge the two data together by telling `panads` to merge along `STATE` column.

```
deaths_per_state = intermediate_df["DEATHS"] / covid_df["DEATHS"].sum()
# Rename the column to "Deaths pct"
deaths_per_state = pd.DataFrame(deaths_per_state).rename(columns={"DEATHS": "Deaths pct"})
# Merge the two
covid_df = pd.merge(covid_df, deaths_per_state, on="STATE")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! It helped me understand what I was doing wrong. The only thing I'll say is that a well documented exception should be thrown in this instance. Allowing an unaligned (in terms of indexes) assignment to happen with NaNs is a bit confusing.
EDIT: Accepting this answer since it shows how to do the merge.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the operations on `intermediate_df` but adding the result to `covid_df`. Do the operations, and save them on `intermediate_df` then you can do a `pd.merge` for both data frames.